# UDP packet is not accepted by server?

Tags: sockets

Packet #1:

```
0000   08 00 27 7f 25 ae 08 00 27 2d 93 13 08 00 45 00   ..'.%®..'-....E.
0010   00 22 ab cd 40 00 40 11 00 00 0a 00 00 e8 0a 00   ."«Í@.@......è..
0020   00 87 22 b8 22 b8 00 0e 00 00 48 65 6c 6c 6f 0a   .."¸"¸....Hello.


Frame 1692: 48 bytes on wire (384 bits), 48 bytes captured (384 bits) on     interface 0
    Interface id: 0 (eth0)
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: Aug 18, 2020 22:47:52.475803259 EDT
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1597805272.475803259 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.198748689 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 35.744487538 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 507.094545999 seconds]
    Frame Number: 1692
    Frame Length: 48 bytes (384 bits)
    Capture Length: 48 bytes (384 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:udp:data]
    [Coloring Rule Name: UDP]
    [Coloring Rule String: udp]
Ethernet II, Src: PcsCompu_2d:93:13 (08:00:27:2d:93:13), Dst:     PcsCompu_7f:25:ae (08:00:27:7f:25:ae)
    Destination: PcsCompu_7f:25:ae (08:00:27:7f:25:ae)
        Address: PcsCompu_7f:25:ae (08:00:27:7f:25:ae)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address  (factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        Source: PcsCompu_2d:93:13 (08:00:27:2d:93:13)
        Address: PcsCompu_2d:93:13 (08:00:27:2d:93:13)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.0.0.232, Dst: 10.0.0.135
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
    Total Length: 34
    Identification: 0xabcd (43981)
    Flags: 0x4000, Don't fragment
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header checksum: 0x0000 [validation disabled]
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
    Source: 10.0.0.232
    Destination: 10.0.0.135
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 8888, Dst Port: 8888
Data (6 bytes)
    Data: 48656c6c6f0a
    [Length: 6]
```

Packet #2:

```
0000   08 00 27 7f 25 ae 08 00 27 2d 93 13 08 00 45 00   ..'.%®..'-....E.
0010   00 22 fa 39 40 00 40 11 2b 23 0a 00 00 e8 0a 00   ."ú9@.@.+#...è..
0020   00 87 cd 36 22 b8 00 0e 15 8e 48 65 6c 6c 6f 0a   ..Í6"¸....Hello.


    Frame 2078: 48 bytes on wire (384 bits), 48 bytes captured (384 bits) on interface 0
    Interface id: 0 (eth0)
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: Aug 18, 2020 22:50:12.624196163 EDT
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1597805412.624196163 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.804243424 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 140.148392904 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 647.242938903 seconds]
    Frame Number: 2078
    Frame Length: 48 bytes (384 bits)
    Capture Length: 48 bytes (384 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:udp:data]
    [Coloring Rule Name: UDP]
    [Coloring Rule String: udp]
Ethernet II, Src: PcsCompu_2d:93:13 (08:00:27:2d:93:13), Dst:     PcsCompu_7f:25:ae (08:00:27:7f:25:ae)
    Destination: PcsCompu_7f:25:ae (08:00:27:7f:25:ae)
        Address: PcsCompu_7f:25:ae (08:00:27:7f:25:ae)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Source: PcsCompu_2d:93:13 (08:00:27:2d:93:13)
        Address: PcsCompu_2d:93:13 (08:00:27:2d:93:13)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.0.0.232, Dst: 10.0.0.135
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
    Total Length: 34
    Identification: 0xfa39 (64057)
    Flags: 0x4000, Don't fragment
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header checksum: 0x2b23 [validation disabled]
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
    Source: 10.0.0.232
    Destination: 10.0.0.135
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 52534, Dst Port: 8888
```

Data (6 bytes)
Data: 48656c6c6f0a
[Length: 6]

Note: the packet is captured by wireshark.

**Tool Source-code**: https://github.com/MrMindKeeper/tcpf/blob/master/crafty.py

**Parameters I use to generate the packet:** `python3 packetP.py -s="10.0.0.232" -d="10.0.0.135" -dmac="08:00:27:7f:25:ae" -smac="08:00:27:2d:93:13" -sp="8888" -dp="8888" -ch="0" -tl="34" -flag="4" -hc="0"`

If you haven't noticed the only difference between the two packets are the IP Header Checksum and IP Header Identification Bytes or (Byte 19-20 and 25-26).

Packet #1 is generated by a tool I personally developed and packet #2 is generated by `netcat` both in the same linux machine.

Server is listening on port 8888. Both packets are received by server but responds to only packet #2 or packet generated by `netcat`.

I also tried bunch other random `IP Header Identification` values, setting Header Checksum to `00 00`, yet still it doesn't work. Can someone tell me what is the problem here and why isn't the packet generated by my tool not accepted?

I guess, you wouldn't need my tool code for the problem because the packets are sent and received. so, there couldn't be a problem with the tool.

Comment: Is it a case of the network stack dropping Packet #1 because it has the wrong checksum-value?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452716/are-udp-packets-dropped-when-udp-header-checksum-is-incorrect/18452930

Comment: *"... because the packets are sent and received. so, there couldn't be a problem with the tool."* - If you do use raw sockets then you also can construct and send invalid packets. They also get received and are shown by wireshark. But they are then thrown away by the OS kernel of the recipient, i.e. after the wireshark capture. So likely you construct the packet the wrong way.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich updated the question with packet fields in clear-text

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I set the checksum to `00 00` but it still didn't work!

Comment: *"...  the only difference between the two packets are the IP Header Checksum and IP Header Identification Bytes ..."* - at least the source port is different too and set to the same value as the destination port. Don't know if this is relevant though. But note that local firewall rules also get applied only after the packet capture, i.e. it might be blocked by a firewall rule but you can see it in wireshark. Also, nothing is known about the server and what you mean with *"packets are received by server"* and with *"but responds to only packet #2"*, i.e. how do you check for response.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich sorry when I update the question, I had to update the packet data too. and no there isn't any firewall to take under consideration. I see the response in client or when the server respond. prints the data sent.

Comment: @ITried: still, nothing is known how exactly you test, how you determine that your server receives packets, that you determine that your server does not respond, what you even mean with server in all places (sometimes the host, sometimes the program). I would imagine that the real problem is somewhere in these details you did not provide. Please provide a reproducible setup with exact description and no ambiguous terms.

Comment: I haven't checked it, but if only the checksum is different (IPID doesn't matter), and one doesn't work, there's a good chance you didn't calculate the checksum correctly. Of course the checksum *should* be different in both packets since the IPID is different. You could also try sending one with the same IPID and see what checksum you get.

Comment: @user253751 I have linked my tool source code in my question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich linked my tool source code above, can you please have a look?

Comment: @ITried: In order to reproduce the issue it is not sufficient to have the tool which generated the packets but it is also necessary to have the server program which should receive and respond to the packet.

Comment: @ITried: it is not sufficient to have the tool which generated the packets but it is also necessary to have the server program which should receive and respond to the packet.